# Windows programming win32

Tags: winapi

I am trying to get menu/submenu name on mouse left click.For this i need to get some notification when i click on that particular menu/submenu.Look if somebody has the idea to do that?

Comment: Could you eleborate more details?, for example, the codes you trying now, more detail explanations about your problem.

Comment: I am trying to get menu/submenu name on mouse left click.For this i need to get some notification when i click on that particular menu/submenu.GetMenuItemInfo gives menu/submenu name if i pass menu index into that.Can you please help?

Answer (score 3):

Instead of reacting to `WM_LBUTTONDOWN` for a menu, you should instead listen for the [`WM_COMMAND`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms647591(VS.85).aspx) notification. Windows takes care of all the details of handling mouse movement and clicks within menus.

Comment: The WM_CONTEXTMENU message is what you should use, not WM_COMMAND or WM_LBUTTONDOWN.

Comment: The WM_CONTEXTMENU notification is for a *right click* (or Shift+F10 or the context menu key), not for a *left click* as the original question requested.

Comment: Greg, thnx for reply.WM_COMMAND is not giving any notification when i click on menu/submenu.Please help.

Comment: I can't suggest any more than I already have unless you post some of your source code.

Answer (score 0):

To work with menu/submenu there is a totally different WMs is
Look in MSDN for this WM_MENUSELECT for example

Comment: Thnx ginger.But WM_MENUSELECT is not working while clicking on menu/submenu.

Comment: Sorry dude, but if this
""The WM_MENUSELECT message is sent to a menu's owner window when the user selects a menu item."" from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646352(VS.85).aspx
do not work for you (even thought it works for others)
I can't help you more :))